# Trying to send data to android using socketServer in Java

Tags: java, android, socketserver

I'm making some sort of scoreboard controlled by an android app.

I got working sending data to the server, but I'm trying to sync the score on my `JFrame` and on my android app, but it's not working.

Can't see why it isn't working, I can send data to the server from the app, but not backwards, here is the code:

```
public class server {

    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static Socket clientSocket;
    private static InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
    private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private static BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream;
    private static OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter;
    private static String message;
    public String ipadd;
    public String ip;
    public controller control;
    public pantalla Controlador;

    public void run() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Nope Port!");
        }

        while (true) {
            try {

                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

                ipadd = String.valueOf(clientSocket.getInetAddress());
                ipadd = ipadd.substring(1, (ipadd.length()));
                controller.ipAddress.setText("IP: " + ipadd);

                inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                message = bufferedReader.readLine();

                OutputStream os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                bw.write(controller.txtRedScore2.getText());
                bw.flush();

                switch (message) {
                    case "redUp":
                        controller.btnUpRed.doClick();
                        break;
                    case "redDown":
                        controller.btnDownRed.doClick();
                        break;
                    case "blueUp":
                        controller.btnUpBlue.doClick();
                        break;
                    case "blueDown":
                        controller.btnDownBlue.doClick();
                        break;
                    case "update":
                        controller.btnStart.doClick();
                        break;
                    case "x1":
                        controller.tglByOne.doClick();
                        break;
                    case "x5":
                        controller.tglByFive.doClick();
                        break;
                    case "x10":
                        controller.tglByTen.doClick();
                        break;
                    case "x20":
                        controller.tglByTwenty.doClick();
                        break;
                    case "x50":
                        controller.tglByFifty.doClick();
                        break;
                }

                inputStreamReader.close();
                clientSocket.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Nope!!" + ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now here's my android app

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button redUp;
    private Button redDown;
    private Button blueUp;
    private Button blueDown;
    private Button update;
    private Button x1;
    private Button x5;
    private Button x10;
    private Button x20;
    private Button x50;
    private Socket client;
    private Socket server;
    private PrintWriter printwriter;
    public String message;
    public String score;
    private TextView redScore;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        redUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.redUp);
        redDown = (Button) findViewById(R.id.redDown);
        blueUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blueUp);
        blueDown = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blueDown);
        update = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update);
        x1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.x1);
        x5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.x5);
        x10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.x10);
        x20 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.x20);
        x50 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.x50);
        redScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.redScore);

        redUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                message = "redUp";
                SendMessage sendMessageTask = new SendMessage();
                sendMessageTask.execute();
            }
        });

        redDown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                message = "redDown";
                SendMessage sendMessageTask = new SendMessage();
                sendMessageTask.execute();
            }
        });

        blueUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                message = "blueUp";
                SendMessage sendMessageTask = new SendMessage();
                sendMessageTask.execute();
            }
        });

        blueDown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                message = "blueDown";
                SendMessage sendMessageTask = new SendMessage();
                sendMessageTask.execute();
            }
        });

        update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                message = "update";
                SendMessage sendMessageTask = new SendMessage();
                sendMessageTask.execute();
            }
        });

        x1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                message = "x1";
                SendMessage sendMessageTask = new SendMessage();
                sendMessageTask.execute();
            }
        });

        x5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                message = "x5";
                SendMessage sendMessageTask = new SendMessage();
                sendMessageTask.execute();
            }
        });

        x10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                message = "x10";
                SendMessage sendMessageTask = new SendMessage();
                sendMessageTask.execute();
            }
        });

        x20.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                message = "x20";
                SendMessage sendMessageTask = new SendMessage();
                sendMessageTask.execute();
            }
        });

        x50.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                message = "x50";
                SendMessage sendMessageTask = new SendMessage();
                sendMessageTask.execute();
            }
        });
    }

    private class SendMessage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                client = new Socket("192.168.11.23", 4444);
                printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
                printwriter.write(message);
                printwriter.flush();
                printwriter.close();

                InputStream is = client.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                score = br.readLine();
                redScore.setText(score);
                Log.v("TEST", "--> " + score + " <--");
                client.close();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the server really receiving the command sent by the client? Did you see it come in in the server? How?

Comment: `printwriter.write(message);`. The server tries to read a line. So the client should send a line. Change to `printwriter.write(message+"\n");`. Remove `printwriter.close();`. You should add that \n also where the server sends its text.

Comment: `switch (message) `. Does that compile?

Comment: @greenapps Yes it compile. I'm going to try changing the printwriter.